# Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate search with elasticsearch as my index manager. Currently, my jvm is set to use 1gb of memory and i do not wish to increase the memory.

I have a `@Transactional` class that inserts a total of 2 million rows for an indexed `@Entity`.

Although the inserts are successful, lucene indexer is running out of memory causing a rollback of the transaction. Below are my hibernate-search configs and the exception stack trace:

```
hibernate.search.default.indexmanager = elasticsearch
elastic= hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host =http://localhost:9200
hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy = CREATE
#should be green for prod
hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status = yellow
hibernate.search.elasticsearch.scroll_backtracking_window_size=10000
hibernate.search.elasticsearch.scroll_fetch_size=1000
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator(HashMap.java:917)
    at java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:173)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1039)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1038)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:212)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-08-15 11:37:53.184 ERROR 10624 --- [nsport thread-1] o.a.h.i.n.c.InternalHttpAsyncClient      : I/O reactor terminated abnormally

org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOReactorException: I/O dispatch worker terminated abnormally
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:356) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.9.jar:4.4.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:194) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator(HashMap.java:917) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1039) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1038) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:212) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.9.jar:4.4.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.9.jar:4.4.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.9.jar:4.4.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.9.jar:4.4.9]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Is there any tuning that can help mitigate this?

Comment: Tuning GC or trying out Java 10 where G1 was improved might help. However the GC tuning will require additional heap memory to pinpoint the problem, so one way or another you will be increasing the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the Hibernate Search indexer triggers the `OutOfMemoryError`, it doesn't mean the Hibernate Search indexer is the one consuming too much memory. It just happened to cross the memory limit, but the problem might also lie in how your entity persistence code behaves. To be clear, if the rest of your JVM takes up 999MB and Hibernate Search only allocates 2MB, Hibernate Search will trigger the `OutOfMemoryError` if it requests memory last.

Now, the most likely problem when persisting/indexing lots of data is that you did not take any precaution in your code, simply looping and adding more and more changes to the transaction, thereby forcing Hibernate ORM and Search to store more and more data in internal buffers until the transaction is finally committed.

Unless you're using the JMS backend (which is hard and I wouldn't recommend), the only solutions I know of will force you to lose a little bit of "transactionality", meaning that a failure in your process will leave your data in an inconsistent state.

The first, perhaps more correct, solution, would be for you to not use a single, big transaction, but multiple smaller ones. For example create a transaction for each chunk of 200 elements. Of course this means if a chunk fails, the previous chunks will still be in the database, but in many cases this might not matter, as you can just restart from where you failed, and the index would still be in sync with the database.

Spring gives you control over transactions using [transaction templates](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html), so you can manually start a new transaction for each chunk of 200 elements, or just refactor your code to put the `@Transactional` annotation at the right place.

The second solution would be for you to still use a single, big transaction, but during the transaction periodically flush your changes, both to the database (which would be able to rollback the changes later if the transaction is aborted, don't worry) and to the index (which would *not* be able to rollback the changes later). This means in particular that if the transaction fails, you would have to restart everything *and* purge the index, because it would not be in sync with the database (which rolled back the changes) anymore.

You can find an example using periodic flushing in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-flushtoindexes

If you adapt the example, your code will look more or less like this:

```
// Execute the code below inside a transaction
Session session = ...;
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession( session );
int index = 0;
while(results.next()) {
    index++;

    // TODO: add code here to insert one row

    if (index % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
        session.flush(); //apply changes to the database
        fullTextSession.flushToIndexes(); //apply changes to indexes
        fullTextSession.clear(); //free memory since the queue is processed
    }
}
```